# Unable to fill Javafx Table View from database

Tags: java, database, javafx

I would like to add values to a Javafx Table.

The values are stored in a remote database.

The method for getting values out of the db (`setAll(service.listReservierung()`) works as intended. When I try to run the following code in order to put the values in the Javafx table, I get a whole list of errors, the first one being a Null pointer exception.
Here's the code:

```
public void listReserv() {
  try {

    AlleReservTable.getItems().setAll(service.listReservierung());

    tableColumnReservNr.setCellValueFactory(
             new PropertyValueFactory<Reservierung, Integer>("reservNr"));

    tableColumnReservName.setCellValueFactory(
             new PropertyValueFactory<Reservierung, String>("kundeName"));

    tableColumnReservVon.setCellValueFactory(
             new PropertyValueFactory<Reservierung, Timestamp>("von"));

    tableColumnReservBis.setCellValueFactory(
             new PropertyValueFactory<Reservierung, Timestamp>("bis"));

 } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Comment: At which line does the NullPointerException arise? Have you initiated table columns?

Comment: At the first one, if i comment that one out, then at the second one, and so on... How do I initiate the table columns?

Comment: If the class is not a JavaFX controller class, i.e. if table columns are not defined in FXML, then you should initiate them. For example: TableColumn<Reservierung, Timestamp> tableColumnReservNr = new TableColumn<>("Reserv Nr"); and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej, i made a working example for you, i used the new Date Time API of Java8.
The ReservationService does not query the database, to check this case, you'll have to post your Service class. Maybe this example will help you.

FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:controller="de.professional_webworkx.reservationmanager.controller.MainController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children><TableView fx:id="reservationTable" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="resNumber" minWidth="250.0" prefWidth="250.0" text="ReservationID" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="customerName" minWidth="450.0" prefWidth="500.0" text="CustomerName" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="checkIn" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="CheckIn" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="checkOut" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="CheckOut" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
  </columns>
</TableView>
</children></AnchorPane>
```

MainController

```
package de.professional_webworkx.reservationmanager.controller;

import de.professional_webworkx.reservationmanager.business.ReservationService;
import de.professional_webworkx.reservationmanager.model.Reservation;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 * Main FXML Controller
 * @author Patrick Ott <Patrick.Ott@professional-webworkx.de>
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    TableView<Reservation> reservationTable;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Reservation, Integer> resNumber;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Reservation, String> customerName;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Reservation, ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime>> checkIn;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Reservation, ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime>> checkOut;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        ReservationService service = new ReservationService();
        List<Reservation> allReservations = service.getAllReservations();
        reservationTable.getItems().addAll(allReservations);
        resNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("reserveNumber"));
        customerName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("customerName"));
        checkIn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checkIn"));
        checkOut.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checkOut"));
    }


}
```

Reservation Entity

```
package de.professional_webworkx.reservationmanager.model;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 * Reservation entity
 * @author Patrick Ott <Patrick.Ott@professional-webworkx.de>
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Reservation {

    private IntegerProperty reserveNumberProperty;
    private StringProperty customerNameProperty;

    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> checkIn;
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> checkOut;

    public Reservation() {
        reserveNumberProperty   = new SimpleIntegerProperty(generateReservationNumber());
        customerNameProperty    = new SimpleStringProperty();
        checkIn                 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        checkOut                = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    }

    public Reservation(final String customerName, final LocalDate checkIn, final LocalDate checkOut) {
        reserveNumberProperty   = new SimpleIntegerProperty(generateReservationNumber());
        customerNameProperty    = new SimpleStringProperty(customerName);
        this.checkIn            = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(checkIn);
        this.checkOut           = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(checkOut);
    }

    /**
     * @return the reserveNumberProperty
     */
    public IntegerProperty getReserveNumberProperty() {
        return reserveNumberProperty;
    }

    public Integer getReserveNumber() {
        return reserveNumberProperty.get();
    }

    /**
     * @param reserveNumberProperty the reserveNumberProperty to set
     */
    public void setReserveNumberProperty(IntegerProperty reserveNumberProperty) {
        this.reserveNumberProperty = reserveNumberProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerNameProperty
     */
    public StringProperty getCustomerNameProperty() {
        return customerNameProperty;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerNameProperty.get();
    }

    /**
     * @param customerNameProperty the customerNameProperty to set
     */
    public void setCustomerNameProperty(StringProperty customerNameProperty) {
        this.customerNameProperty = customerNameProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the checkIn
     */
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> getCheckInProperty() {
        return checkIn;
    }

    public LocalDate getCheckIn() {
        return checkIn.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @param fromProperty the checkIn to set
     */
    public void setCheckInProperty(ObjectProperty<LocalDate> fromProperty) {
        this.checkIn = fromProperty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the checkOut
     */
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> getCheckOutProperty() {
        return checkOut;
    }

    public LocalDate getCheckOut() {
        return checkOut.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @param toProperty the checkOut to set
     */
    public void setCheckOutProperty(ObjectProperty<LocalDate> toProperty) {
        this.checkOut = toProperty;
    }

    private Integer generateReservationNumber() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int nextInt = random.nextInt();
        return new Integer(nextInt);
    }
}
```

ReservationService

```
package de.professional_webworkx.reservationmanager.business;

import de.professional_webworkx.reservationmanager.model.Reservation;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * ReservationService
 * persist, query, delete, edit Reservations
 * @author Patrick Ott <Patrick.Ott@professional-webworkx.de>
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class ReservationService {

    public ReservationService() {
        super();
    }

    public List<Reservation> getAllReservations() {
        List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();
        // fetch all reservations from database
        reservations.add(new Reservation("Patrick", LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(3)));
        reservations.add(new Reservation("userXYZ", LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(2)));
        return reservations;
    }
}
```

And start it

```
package de.professional_webworkx.reservationmanager;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Patrick Ott <Patrick.Ott@professional-webworkx.de>
 */
public class ReservationManager extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hotel Reservation Manager v1.0");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```